# I like pigeons, And I like to make homing pigeon for my house, is it good act or bad?

Tags: animals

actually I love any kind of animal, I had some birds like Nightingale, White-eared bulbul and so many others, even snake mouse and so..., That time I was child, some one said, you not love them, they love to be free, not in cage and you slave them, after that I did not keep any kind of animal anymore (as you said pet), I don't have pet for a long times

But know I see many people that have homing pigeon, they are free and they come back to their cage freely, or in other way the special kind of pigeon which known as dove or white dove or ring-neck dove with it's extremely calm character somehow seems that it can not stay alive in wild world.

so what about keeping pigeon that they became homing pigeon actually I should say we training them to became homing pigeon, or others that need to human take care of them like dove? are this act known as slavery? Is it wrong?

even though this is not good excuse to cage them either for homing pigeon and for other need to take care, but I searching for straight and clear answer and wise explanation

are these slave? does it acceptable in Buddhism? This is virtuous act? how we can explain it that is either good or bad?

Answer (score 1):

It can be accepted if the animal lives freely around your home and garden,Otherwise if he lives in a cage, It should be kept opened always, so that animal can fly away and comeback when it needs..
However you have to get the decision whether it makes a wrong  effect towards the animal or not,if it's you have to give up  that, We can't see the effects on the pigeon you keep  by making it a home growing animal..If you see, it losses   advantages living in natural environment are more than it gains by home growing, you have to release it,like that you have to think and decide,you are the best one to decide that as you can see in it better than us..Simply if it gets bad effects more than good ones by keeping at home,except natural environment let it go back to natural environment

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

If I left the cage open all the time, so it will be good dinner or breakfast for cat or other kind of these animal.
and about living in nature and In cage, so If we think about long span of living in cage as an advantage so many person that are prison may like that, so thanks for the points

Comment: @Alireza shahbazi Think in this way,think yourself as a pigeon who lives in natural world first, then a certain person comes and catch you and cages you..Now you are in the cage, what do you think now,do you feel living in the cage better than natural environment you lived earlier, if so you can think about keep pigeon in the cage..If you don't like to live in cage, you have to release the animal

Comment: this is in the way of human not the way of animals, It can divided into two way, one way we added the human character If we apply these somehow we can not apply the correct answer in general because it is not human and it's needs are different, the other way we may somehow apply the human roles that may not even good for them we can find specials, But as I said the example of prison I Agree with you.

Comment: ''Sabbe thasanthi dandassa Sabbe bhayanthi machhuno Attanan upaman kathwa Na haneyya na ghathaye''here buddha says us to compare yourself with an animal/human or any living being before harm him/it...So there is no barrier you can compare yourself with an animal,that mean you can think yourself as an animal..The reason is any living being has mind, and can think, so you can understand what it/he think by thinking yourself as that animal.. As the complete mean of this verse after you compared yourself with that animal/human if it doesn't like what you going to do,don't do it

Comment: A kindhearted and thoughtful answer. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have explained it, I feel that, if the bird is free to roam then no amount of violence is done on the bird, so if it is really that important for your welbeing, it is fine. You can keep it. This is definitely not a slavery and there are no doctorines against keeping homing pegions.

But there is following problem with domasticating exotic animals.

1. You will be buying those birds somewhere probable a pet shop, that pet shop owner will be getting them from the wild or may be breeding them. It encourages their business. Along with the homing pegions they also deal with other exotic species which are seriously not meant for human homes. This disturbs natural eco-systems. My friend once had a rabbit in his house, but that rabbit was some fox's dinner. This is disturbance in the eco-system. I am not saying the world will crash with your buying the pegion, but in a way you end up encouraging that entire business.
2. Some fools, when they will see your pegions wont be as thoughtful as you are. They will search on internet and buy tropical exotic species. Just go on NatGeo and look for yourself the nuisance of animal smuggling.

If its for the love of animals as you said, if I were you join the conservation efforts. You go save their home rather than bringing them to your home.

Comment: thank you, the eco-system and business is scientific and politics point, so as you said for making home pigeon we should first buy it and then train it to be home pigeon other wise they don't come back. that's completely right to joining the conservation efforts and best idea, but what about If we want to having a pet to feel it is for us and we are the owner. maybe this ownership is the source of problem?!! or enjoying which is one way?! Actually what is the kind of this enjoying??

Comment: From a Buddhist point of view its all jusy fine as you have made up your mind. That enjoying is same as enjoying anyother possession.

Comment: the level of mind is also significant,  Thanks

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: See Maslow's Hierarchy of Needs

Comment: It seriously is irrelevent to Buddhism.